# Server does not receive data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem. I'm trying to send content of a textarea with an ajax call, but it doesn't seem to be working, and I don't know why.

There's the method called `GetStatus(string statusText)` which need to receive the content.

Here's the javascript code:

```
$("#btnSaveStatus").on("click", function () {
                    var statusText = $(".textareaEdit").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetStatus",
                        data: "{statusText:'" + statusText + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
//                            $('#littlbioID').text(result.d);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Please advise. You should also know that I'm new into web development.

Comment: What does your server code look like?  that JS looks good, but it is expecting a json response, if it doesn't get a valid json response it won't work. Add an error property to handle an error

Comment: My server method doesn't have any context yet... I only tried to verify if the statusText is sent to the server, by putting a breakpoint in the beginning, but nothing happened.

Comment: [WebMethod]
        protected void GetStatus(object statusText)
        {
            string _statusText = statusText.ToString();
        }

Comment: I only need to send the "textareaEdit" content (after I filter the content). There's the method on the server that sends the text into the db; the method doesn't necessarily have to respond the client nothing, a json or any data response. 

    protected void GetStatus(object statusText)
    {
          // verify and send "statusText" to db
    }


I have 2 questions:

-is the [webmethod] attribute mandatory?

-are the contentType, dataType and succes attributes 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't have a request body in a GET request, you have to use a POST request for that
2. The string you are constrcting is not valid JSON since:

   - Property names must be strings
   - You have no idea what the user will enter in the textarea - it might contain characters with special meaning in JSON

Generate your JSON programatically.

```
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/GetStatus",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    statusText: statusText
  }),
  // etc
```

Obviously, the server side of the process needs to be set up to accept a POST request with a JSON body (instead of the more standard URL Form Encoded format) as well.

Comment: It's actually not necessary at all to stringify the object. jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: @IngoBürk — It will stringify it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnSaveStatus").on("click", function () {
                    var statusText = $(".textareaEdit").val();
                    var jsonText = new Object();
                    jsonText.statusText = statusText;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetStatus",
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonText);,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
//                            $('#littlbioID').text(result.d);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: After your edit, you are constructing JSON in an unsafe way. It depends on the user entering data into the form which doesn't contain any characters which are invalid or have special meaning in JSON. If they type a new line, `"` or ``\`` then it will either break or produce undesired results.